# Unity WebGL export having trouble on Kongregate: Soft.psd and UnitySplash.cube.png

Tags: html, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, kongregate

I exported an html5 version of my mobile game and put it on flash/html5 websites, it usually works, though Kongregate has difficulties with my game. I use Unity 5.3.1p4, though I had the same issue with previous versions as well.

I run into the following errors:

> The resource Soft.psd could not be loaded from the resource file!
>
> The resource UnitySplash-cube.png could not be loaded from the resource
> file!

The error message is thrown 133 times and afterwards the game stops loading/crashes.

I had other issues with kongregate before (often times its the "run out of memory" issue), but this is a new one, anybody encounter this before?

Comment: kongregate is pretty crappy. it sounds like the sort of minor problem one constantly runs in to with it; hope there's a clear solution but sadly it's likely there is no real solution

Comment: kongregate might be crappy but its also the site that has the most users, which is why I have to continue trying :/

Comment: sure, good luck and I hope you can patch around it!  as you know, unity -> web is still a bit flakey  :/

Comment: I don't really have a deadline, I will just continue trying out new versions of unity and hopefully it will fix itself eventually ;) Unity+Webgl looks very promising, hope it continues to improve in 2016!

Comment: purely one man's opinion, even in U6 (say early 2017) it will still be flakey.  anyways sure, good luck!